# How to set responseURL of request object using msw (Mock service worker)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

Environment:  Jest, Node, React, msw + rest + setupSever

How to set request.responseURL using msw

**Attempt**

```
rest.get('*'), (req, res, ctx) => {
  req.responseURL = 'abc'
  return res(
   ctx.json({}),
)
```

**Attempt**

```
rest.get('*'), (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(
   ctx.json({}),
   ctx.set('responseURL', 'url')
)
```

**Attempt**

```
rest.get('*'), (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(
   ctx.status(302),
   ctx.set('Location', 'url')
)
```

**Attempt**

```
import { rest } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
....

rest.get('*'), (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res((res) => {
    ....
    res.request.responseURL = 'xyz';
    return res
 })

}
```

This lib is not allowing to mock/update request object of response, is there a way?

Comment: you can update the request, req.abc = "xyz"?
that the way in expressJS. you do not allow touch the req by res but req and res know each other.
many libraries build under req object and use it in res. (passport. cookieParser and more)

Comment: HI, thanks!!  That was my first attempt, but didn't work either. When I was updating req, it raise Network error. (in both ways)

Earlier I tried following: 

```
req.abc = 'xyz';
res.get('*'), (...) => {
return res( ctx.json({...}) )
```

The only way i can add/update prop in request is by using set(), but it add prop only in header part (not in root of request).

Comment: Can you please share why do you wish to set a `responseURL`? The mocked response instance that `res` represents doesn't have a `request` property, not the `responseURL` property. Response URL should be automatically set by MSW.